# How to export pdf report in jasper reports

Tags: grails, browser, jasper-reports, download

I want to export a report as pdf and it should ask the user for a download location.  How do I do this in grails?

This is my code:

```
def exportToPdf(JasperPrint jasperPrint,String path,request){

    String cur_time =System.currentTimeMillis();
    JRExporter pdfExporter = null;

    pdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();

    log.debug("exporting to file..."+JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "C:\\pdfReport"+cur_time+".pdf"));

    return ;
}
```

In jasper controller:

```
/**
   * Generate a html response.
   */
  def generateResponse = {reportDef ->
    if (!reportDef.fileFormat.inline && !reportDef.parameters._inline) {
      response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + reportDef.name + "." + reportDef.fileFormat.extension + "\"");
      response.contentType = reportDef.fileFormat.mimeTyp
      response.characterEncoding = "UTF-8"
      response.outputStream << reportDef.contentStream.toByteArray()
    } else {
      render(text: reportDef.contentStream, contentType: reportDef.fileFormat.mimeTyp, encoding: reportDef.parameters.encoding ? reportDef.parameters.encoding : 'UTF-8');
    }
  }
```

Comment: I want user to manually select the download options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Jasper Plugin?](http://grails.org/plugin/jasper)  It seems to have the tools already built for you.  As far as asking the user for a download location the browser has *some* controller over how files are received from a web page.  Is your real issue that you want control over the download location?

[UPDATE]

Using the location 'c:\' is on your server **not** the client and this is why it is not downloading.

try something like this...

```
def controllerMethod = {
    def temp_file = File.createTempFile("jasperReport",".pdf") //<-- you don't have to use a temp file but don't forget to delete them off the server at some point.

    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, temp_file.absolutePath));

    response.setContentType("application/pdf")  //<-- you'll have to handle this dynamically at some point
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=${temp_file.getName()}")
    response.outputStream << temp_file.newInputStream() //<-- binary stream copy to client



}
```

**I have not tested this and there are better ways of handling the files and streams but i think you'll get the general idea.**

Comment: it is successfully creating pdf file but while it is not asking to save or open the file

Comment: i am calling exportToPdf in groovy file  method from my controller action where i have written exportReportToPdfFile .so we cant set response properties .

Comment: If you want to download a file from a browser you need to set the response properties.  You can't just access the user disk through the browser (thank god!).  I believe the jasper plugin for grails hides some of the downloading boilerplate code from you so you don't have to deal with the response properties.

Comment: can i use session-temp-files plugin to put the pdf reports in temp directory on server

Comment: Seems like a good idea.  As i mentioned above there are better ways of handling the files and streams.  This is one of them.  Was my answer helpful?

Comment: File is downloading automatically in C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\jasperReport4586921643992539176.pdf ,again the same problem

Comment: right, makes sense.  Now you need to send that file to the end user using the response.outputStream.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Lee let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1689/discussion-between-vinay-and-michael-j-lee)