# Grails Jasper: Displaying property/-ies from java.lang.Object

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, ireport

I have this problem regarding my Jasper Report on Grails wherein I should display the contents of a particular model having this properties

```
class Schedule {
  Subject subject
  Room room // another class having only a single property [room:String]
  DayOfWeek day //days of the week having only a single property [day:String]
  String timeStart
  String timeEnd
  //constraints
}
class Subject {
   Course course
   String section
   static hasMany = [schedule: Schedule]
   // constraints
}
```

The problem is that when I try to call the action from the controller where the `jasperReport` will be getting the `Schedule.list()`, I get this error in return

```
URI     /Portal/jasper/index
Class   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException
Message could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Here's the controller and view code.

```
// ScheduleController
def report() {
   List scheduleList = Schedule.list()
   chain(controller:'jasper', action:'index', params:params,
         model:[data:scheduleList])
}

//view
<g:jasperReport jasper="schedule_list"
                controller="schedule"
                action="report"
                format="pdf, html"
                name="Schedule List"
                description=" " />
```

---

In attempt to resolve this problem, I tried to parse the properties in the domain using this theory below. But in return the report returns all fields on the report `null` having the correct number of records.

```
List scheduleList = Schedule.list().collect {
   [cell:
      [it.subject.toString(),
       it.room.toString(),
       it.day.toString(),
       it.timeStart,
       it.timeEnd
      ],id: it.id
   ]    
} as List
```

Here's the fields name located in the jasper report [.jrxml]

```
<field name="subject" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="room" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="day" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="timeStart" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="timeEnd" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you please post the relevant controller code?

Comment: @JonoB I edited it with the requirements you seek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with controller chaining is that the domain objects will no longer be attached to a hibernate session, hence the exception.

Instead of chaining, use the JasperService (from your controller) to generate the report, as shown here: http://www.grails.org/plugin/jasper

e.g. something like:

```
class ScheduleController {

    def jasperService

    ...

    def report() {

        // Get the report data and build the report.
        List scheduleList = Schedule.list()
        JasperReportDef reportDef = jasperService.buildReportDefinition(params, request.getLocale(), [data:sheduleList])

        // Non-inline reports (e.g. PDF)
        if (!reportDef.fileFormat.inline && !reportDef.parameters._inline)
        {
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+(reportDef.parameters._name ?: reportDef.name) + "." + reportDef.fileFormat.extension);
            response.contentType = reportDef.fileFormat.mimeTyp
            response.characterEncoding = "UTF-8"
            response.outputStream << reportDef.contentStream.toByteArray()
        }
        else
        {
            // Inline report (e.g. HTML)
            render(text: reportDef.contentStream, contentType: reportDef.fileFormat.mimeTyp, encoding: reportDef.parameters.encoding ? reportDef.parameters.encoding : 'UTF-8');
        }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Am I going to place that in the controller, view, service or the model itself?

Comment: I've tried your answer, but it return an error on my browser 'File not found' having the error message 'Firefox can't find the file at localhost:9090/Portal/schedule/…; when I want to view the report as HTML. What could be error? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the server exception trace.

Comment: There is none. I'm using Jasper as a plugin in Grails on STS and creating the reports using the IReport of Jaspersoft. When I ran the program, the grails console is clean.

Comment: BTW credit for some of this code must go to the author of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758162/how-to-export-pdf-report-in-jasper-reports

Comment: Thanks for the update but after trying your updated answer, it worked with uneccessary marks for the spacing of each component - 'e.g. Static Text'. How can those marks be removed so that the results of the PDF format would be the same for the HTML format?

Comment: Not sure - this is probably a separate question more related to iReport than to the original question.  Your original question has been resolved, yes?